# How to redirect to one level up?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

params.php

```
$minw = 640;

<script>
    var minw = <?php echo $minw;?>;
    var w1 = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if (w1 < minw) {location.href = '../minw.php'};
</script>
```

path to `params.php` and `minw.php` is `localhost/x1/params.php` or `minw.php`.

`params.php` is included in `stone.php` and path to `stone.php` is `localhost/x1/mem/stone.php`.

So, I go to `stone.php` and screen width is less then 640;

I got the browser message - `Object not found` and in the address bar I see: `localhost.minw.php`

Then I changed the code `../minw.php` into `minw.php` or `./minw.php` in `params.php`.

Go again to `stone.php`, got the same browser message and in address bar I see `localhost/x1/mem/minw.php`.

So, how can I redirect from `localhost/x1/mem/stone.php` to `localhost/x1/minw.php` ?

Comment: The way you are passing the PHP to JavaScript is very very bad. The differences between client and server languages and how each is loaded can effect you here

Comment: `location.href = '../minw.php'` in `stone.php` should do the trick. Not sure why you see  `localhost.minw.php`.

Comment: @SterlingArcher, I checked variables using js. alert and it works. What is the better way to pass them from `php` to `js` ?

Comment: @Havenard, I agree, but cannot resolve the mystery.

Comment: Try with `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @bonaca the best way that I know of would be to grab it with ajax. Since the client side runs before the server side, you could be sending an undefined variable somewhere you don't

Comment: Here's a pretty good blogpost http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/

Comment: Tell me how exactly client-side runs before server-side if server-sides generates all client-side sees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new answer that I think will help you:

```
$minw = 640;
echo '<script>
URL = location.href;
var URL = URL.replace("mem/stone.php", "minw.php");
var minw = '.$minw.';
var w1 = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (w1 < minw) {location.href = URL};
</script>';
```

Comment: If you wrapped the echo statement (which I feel is bad practice, but not 100% sure) in the inverse quotes, you wouldn't have to escape the string to put in the variable. Double quotes will parse, singles are literal

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but you should be wary that what works isn't necessarily the best way. :x

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
URL = location.href;
var URL = URL.replace("mem/stone.php", "minw.php");
var minw = <?php echo $minw;?>;
var w1 = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (w1 < minw) {location.href = URL};
```

EDIT: Also I didn't check for errors in your code so beware of that. I only checked if I made any errors. So all the new code on there is probably error free.

Comment: `document.URL` has been deprecated. Use `location.href`.

Comment: MCRocks, thanks I will try you solution, but I must know what is wrong with my code.